# PHPMyAdmin Single Signon Authentication Infinite Redirect Loop

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, debian

I'm attempting to create a single signon platform for a control panel using phpmyadmin. I've ready the tutorial and the surrounding documentation. I installed phpmyadmin and changed the config files and the signon script as follows:

config.inc.php:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'signon';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'TEST';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonURL']     = 'pma.php';
?>
```

pma.php:

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', 0);
session_name('TEST');
session_start();
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_user'] = 'root';
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = 'ROOTPASSWORDHERE';
$_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_host'] = 'localhost';
session_write_close();
header('Location: ./index.php?server=1');
?>
```

Unfortunately when going to the phpmyadmin URL in my browser it auto-loops between pma.php and index.php never actually logging into phpmyadmin. Firefox eventually catches this and stops it "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

A few details about my setup:

I am using nginx with php5-fpm on debian 6 for this. I used apt-get to install phpmyadmin and after the install I created a working nginx config for it. I then tested phpmyadmin by manually entering the root username and password, which worked correctly.

This is just a test, thus I won't be "auto-authenticating" just anyone who connects to the server, I simply want to get it working so I've stripped as much as possible off of the pma.php script.

Comment: Did you ever find out a fix for this? I've been battling with the same problem...

Comment: I did indeed.(See: https://github.com/Feathur/Feathur/blob/Testing/feathur/includes/configs/pma.config.inc.php.example and https://github.com/Feathur/Feathur/blob/Testing/feathur/includes/configs/pma.php.example) -- In my case users who had permissions of '7' in session where admins. You need to make sure your phpmyadmin and your other application both use the same cookie for session.

Comment: Ok thanks. Must be something different then.. Both applications are using the same cookie name and there isn't any problems with permissions etc. Not sure if laravel breaks something up.

Comment: Are you sure your config refrerences the correct cookie? $cfg['Servers'][$i]['SignonSession'] = 'cookie_name';

Comment: Yep. Also checked via browser that the correct cookie name was there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the re-direction it is recommended to change code little bit of pma.php as

```
   <?php
         session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', 0);
         session_name('TEST');
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_user'] = 'root';
         $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = 'ROOTPASSWORDHERE';
         $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_host'] = 'localhost';
         session_write_close();

         if( !isset($_GET[server])){
            header('Location: ./index.php?server=1');
         }

    ?>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me at least. Could you explain why that should help?